# How to make Android app from PHP, HTML and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, web

I made an web application using PHP, HTML and Javascript. 
Now, I want to make it become a Android app.

How to convert an web application into Android app?
What tools I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use android Webview.
Granted you have installed Android studio and the Android SDK you can get started by hosting your website online and linking to the website URL using the webview.

Here is some documentation on how to use webview to build a web app:

https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Please keep in mind that this is slower than a native android application so it is often not preferable.

Comment: +1, my vote is note displayed, thanks for the link. Because it's slower, what  is alternative development tools that can produce native app, easier than Android Studio?

Comment: Please just use android studio, Eclipse ADT plugin might work, although it is no longer supported by google. Would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: Thanks, I accept your answer. I just want to know is there alternatives of android studio which is simpler and lightweight.